# How to convert with ICU?

Tags: c, icu

I have to review the design of a large software (write in C). I have to make it compatible with UNICODE characters. The main purpose is mainly to read and extract the contents of a file that have characters like '老', for example.

My question is: is it possible to convert my current str UTF-16 or do I have to recode?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't have unicode encoding. Have a simple str in my code !

Comment: What format is your file in currently?